# Python: socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] When Attempting To Get IP Address in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, sockets, ip-address, macos-big-sur

I just upgraded my MacBook to macOS Big Sur. Previously on macOS Mojave, the following code still running and outputs the IP Address of the Macbook. But after I upgraded, it just shows up the Errno 8 error. Which was weird. Have anyone encountered this bug before? Thanks.

```py
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print(ip_address)
```

Error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

edit: tried updating my python version to 3.8 but nothing works. still output the same error again for some reason why.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def hostname_ip(hostname):
    hostname = 'google.com'
    addr1 = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    return addr1[2]
```